# Adding /usr/share/mibs/cisco to snmp mib search path

Tags: 12.04, snmp, mib

Is there a way to add arbitrary path (e.g. `/usr/share/mibs/cisco`) to MIB search path?

This is in Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS.

Answer (score 4):

Came out very simple, thanks to rstory-work at #net-snmp irc channel:

Just add the line

```bsh
mibdirs +/usr/share/mibs/cisco
```

to `/etc/snmp/snmp.conf`.

Comment: using the +/- notation in `/etc/snmp/snmp.conf` will just confuse the MIB search path. See my answer below on where this can be used.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [snmp_config man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/snmp_config.5.html) you should add the line `mibdirs -/usr/share/mibs/cisco` to one of the paths below:

```
~/.snmp/snmp.conf
/usr/share/snmp/snmp.conf
```

Use the home directory path if you only want a single user to have access.